# Get name, device name, network category from all network connections with a script

Tags: powershell, networking, connection

I need to get some information about all network connection on a single PC.

I need to get `Name` (eg. Ethernet), `Device Name` (eg. Intel(R) Ethernet Connection) and `Network Category` (eg. public\domain network) of all network adapter used from OC and also get `hostname` of it if it is possible.

I've tried some powershell scripts, but using:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter IPEnabled=TRUE
```

I can get only `hostname` (DNSHostName) and `Device Name` (Description).

There are some different class or object to get all info that i need?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at `Get-NetAdapter` cmdlet yet?

Comment: i can't use Get-NetAdapter on my server

Answer (score 0):

if i use the command:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapter | select SystemName, NetConnectionID, Description
```

i can get 3 of 4 information that i need.

i miss only the network category (eg. domain network, public network). i can't find where it is that info.

Comment: I think `(Get-NetConnectionProfile).NetworkCategory` is the command you are looking for!